# Using Jquery to find the current url to replace /modify the class

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I want to use jquery to edit the class margin properties if its on homepage or admin, for instance , i am using class breadcrumb

```
.breadcrumb{margin-top:10px;margin-left:20px;}
```

What I want is to find the current url which is I think done by using:

```
 var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

After getting the current path I need to check if its admin page or home page or common pages, so for common page , the margin-left should be 15px , while for home and admin page the margin-left should be 20px

Admin page url: www.mydomain.com/admin

home page url: www.mydomain.com

other pages url: www.mydomain.com/......

Can anyone help me how to achieve this , or is there any better way of doing this,
Any help or assistance will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u want to do it using Jquery try like this

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var pathname = "window.location";

            var a=pathname.split('/');

 //checking for admin and home page

            if(a[1]=="admin"||a[1]==""){

                $("body").css("margin-left","20px");


            }

          else{
          $("body").css("margin-left","15px");

           }
        });
```

Comment: var pathname = window.location.path;

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using javascript/jQuery I would prefer to add a special class (e.g. `<body class="admin">` and `<body class="hp">`) for admin pages and hp and I would write this css code

```
.breadcrumb {
    margin-top : 10px; 
    margin-left : 15px;
}

.hp .breadcrumb,
.admin .breadcrumb { margin-left: 20px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Answer (score 1):

i would use .split('/') and then check if the pathname[1] == '', or 'admin', or other

Answer (score 1):

```
if(pathname == admin || pathname == "")
{
 $("body").css("margin-left","20px");
}
else
{
 $("body").css("margin-left","15px");
}
```

write these on document.ready